# Drivermanager cannot be resolved error in tomcat

Tags: jsp, tomcat7

Im trying to  connect mysql database with jsp in tomcat server..im getting the following error please help
    An error occurred at line: 14 in the jsp file: /LoginCheck.jsp
DriverManager cannot be resolved

Comment: check if you set the `mysql-connector` driver in the lib folder ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.sql.*
```

make sure that you have imported this library